# Fastest between mat of Vec2 or 2 Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I have a question concerning access speed of OpenCV matrix.

I currently need two channels of unsigned char to contain my data.
But at one point i need to split my data to process them separately (which probably results in a matrix copy)

```
for( auto ptr = ROI.begin<cv::Vec2b>(); ptr!=ROI.end<cv::Vec2b>();ptr++){
 //insert values
}

cv::split(ROI,channels_vector)

process(channels_vector[0]);
process(channels_vector[1]);

more_stuff(ROI);
```

My question is the following :
Should I use two different matrix at the beginning to avoid the split or let it like this ?
Or as it may depend on my computation what is the difference of cost between two accesses of a matrix and a matrix copy ?

Comment: should depend on how often you access the single channeled versions and the multi channeled versions (with or without the information of both channels at a time).

Comment: I do a canny edge detection and a probabilistic Hough Transform in the process part and in the more_stuff i do a local maximum on every pixel.
Yet the first part (process) should contain more accesses to the matrix than the other part, but to me i guess i gain time inserting a Vec2b rather than 2 times a uchar.